# add a stamp on Email headers when using office.js Add in on Outlook

Tags: javascript, outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to replicate this below behavior on my Office add in for outlook, but I am not able to find the right API to use, can someone help with that?

Does `Office.context.mailbox.item` contains any of the functions needed to do so?

I know that I will need to add the stamp using the `customProperties` as it is related to the email

but how can I add the Stamp?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For just stamping a message in UI, you can try to use outlook categories. Please check [Get and set categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/categories?view=outlook-js-1.12) for available categories API.
For adding the stamp to the message you can either use [custom properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.customproperties?view=outlook-js-1.8) or [internet headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/internet-headers?view=outlook-js-1.12)

Comment: Thank you, 
I believe that custom properties are used to only save data related to an item in outlook and can't be used for this purpose, although the categories might come in handy
is there a way to add an icon for the category?

Comment: @outlook-add-ins-team-msft any plans to support internet headers for appointment items, not only messages?

Comment: @Sora there is no way to add an icon for the category, only colors.

Comment: @Eugene Astafiev Currently internet header for appointments is not a part of the product and we are not planning to add it. Please request for a new feature is this is needed. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our  [Tech Community Page](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process. 
Github Label: “Type: product feature request”